# iOS Application handle storage error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nserror

I am creating an iPad application that will download lot of images from the server and will store in application directory.

I am using `NSOperationQueue` for downloading operation and using following code for saving downloaded images

```
NSError *writeError;
if ([imageData writeToFile:imagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]) {
     // updating UI after downloading completes
 }
 else
 {
     // what are possible errors
     NSLog(@"%@",writeError.debugDescription);
 }
```

**Problem:**

I want to handle storage errors so that I can stop my downloading process and tell user about that error. How I can check those errors? What are codes of those errors and also what other errors should I handle?

Comment: do you want to check error in `file downloading` or `file saving`?

Comment: during file saving, like not enough storage available in the device to save that new image file etc etc.